# How Can I Verify Text Amount in Katalon

Tags: katalon-studio

I'm trying to verify a text in Katalon and my script isn't working.

Here's my element:

```
<span id="overviewTabStoreCredit" class="h2 strong amountCredit text-danger">-$100.00</span>
```

Here's my script:

```
def StoreCreditAmount = '-$100.00'

TestObject StoreCreditTO = findTestObject('Baseline/Page_Side Menu/Page_Customers/Page_Customer Card/span_Verify Credit Limit')

WebUI.verifyElementAttributeValue(StoreCreditTO, 'text', StoreCreditAmount, GlobalVariable.G_Timeout_Tiny, FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)
```

When running the script, I get an error message, "Object does not have attribute 'text'"

I also tried this to character it by class instead of text:

```
def StoreCreditAmount = 'h2 strong amountCredit text-danger'

TestObject StoreCreditTO = findTestObject('Baseline/Page_Side Menu/Page_Customers/Page_Customer Card/span_Verify Credit Limit')

WebUI.verifyElementAttributeValue(StoreCreditTO, 'class', StoreCreditAmount, GlobalVariable.G_Timeout_Tiny, FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)
```

I got this error:
Has attribute 'class' with actual value 'text-success h2 strong amountCredit' instead of expected value 'h2 strong amountCredit text-danger' even though the value is correct.

Answer (score 2):

'Text' might not be an attribute. You can getText() from the element and then compare with the expected result. Sometimes, the value you see might not from Text, but from the attribute 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at your tag there is no "text" attribute:

```
<span id="overviewTabStoreCredit" class="h2 strong amountCredit text-danger">
```

Some elements (like text-boxes) have hidden "value" elements for input text, but that is not the case here.

I believe what you want to do is check that the text between your tags equals a certain amount, in this case: "-$100.00".

To check the text between your opening/closing tags for your element use 
[WebUI.getText()](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-get-text.html#example-). So your code could grab the text between the tags of your element, and then do an assert (or do it in one step) to finish your validation. I'll show it in two for readability:

```
def testStoreCreditAmountText = '-$100.00'

TestObject storeCreditTO = findTestObject('Baseline/Page_Side Menu/Page_Customers/Page_Customer Card/span_Verify Credit Limit')

def actualStoreCreditAmountText = WebUI.getText(storeCreditTO)

WebUI.verifyMatch(testStoreCreditAmountText, actualStoreCreditAmountText, false)
```

I hope that helps!